# Gmail Email Threading

Tags: python, email, gmail

I'm building an CRM and I have included email within it. When I send out an email from my CRM to a gmail account and then reply to it from the gmail account it automatically threads the conversation (within Gmail), however if I then reply to the reply from my CRM it starts a new thread within Gmail.

I read https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/965/how-does-gmail-decide-to-thread-email-messages which states the it is based on the email subject but this doesn't seem to be working a per my issue.

Bearing in mind, when I say I am 'replying' I simply mean I am sending another email with the same subject (to and from the same emails obviously).

The weird thing is, if I send out another email from my CRM with the same subject to the same email it does thread that, just not the reply.

Anyone know why this is happening and how I can fix it?

**UPDATE:**
Probably worth mentioning, I am parsing the replies, so the previous email bodies are not included.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Threading based on subject isn't standard. You should set in-reply-to header to message-id of first email.

Comment: Shouldn't it be the message-id of the message being replied to?  If all replies are to the first message ID you can get out of sequence replies.  Sorting by timestamp isn't sufficient.